# How to display persistent dialogue

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display a persistent message at the bottom of my application(through out all activities) when there's no internet connection, and the message disappears once there's a network connection

I thought about using and application dialog, which I was able to do, but then I realised the background was not clickable, I need users to still have access to navigate pages/menu

something as seen in the picture below

[image]

What I tried with a custom alert dialog

**NoInternetDialog.java**

```
public class NoConnectionDialog {
    public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.no_internet_connection_dialog);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

        wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        window.setAttributes(wlp);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
        text.setText(msg);

//        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
//        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                dialog.dismiss();
//            }
//        });

        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/zxing_viewfinder_laser"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
    app:elevation="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_internet_connection"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and how I call it

```
NoConnectionDialog alert = new NoConnectionDialog();
        alert.showDialog(this, "No Internet Connection");
```

What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `Dialog`, just add that layout to your `Activity`'s layout and set the visibility based on whether the user has an internet connection.  This will avoid all of the issues you'll run into trying to do this with a `Dialog`.  If you have multiple `Activity`s, you could use a common superclass for them that includes this functionality.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by common superclass?

Comment: You could have a `BaseActivity` that extends `Activity` (or whatever subclass your Activities extend currently) and each of your Activities could extend that.  You could put the logic for the internet connection indicator in there.  It could either be in each layout with the same ID, or you could do something tricky with overriding setContentView to wrap the individual layouts.